# Why is there space overhead when deserializing from a binary archive into a std::map

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, boost-serialization, overhead

this is my program:

```
void loadB(map<unsigned int,myParam> & myParams)
{
    std::ifstream ifs("/tmp/all_params", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if( ifs.good() ){
        try{
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
            ia >> myParams;

            ifs.close();
        }catch(boost::archive::archive_exception& ex){
            syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Archive Exception during deserializing params");
        }
    }else{  }
}
```

The size of the file "/tmp/all_params" is 133M but when I load it with the loadB() function the memory consumption is more than 650M(1.7G virtual). Does it make any sense?

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16619 root      20   0 1767468 653772   2988 S   3.7  8.0   0:06.21 engine
```

Comment: To the SSCCE cave...

Comment: Yes. It's possible to have a memory leak without Boost Serialization. This makes it easily possible to have a memory _with_ it.

Comment: Ah. The question is not actually about leaking memory. That was a red herring. The question is about (potential) inefficiency of standard heap allocators

Comment: The question is about "to the SSCCE cave..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it makes sense.

E.g. when `/tmp/all_params` is a file generated with the following program:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/881db067d065c164)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct myParam { 
    std::string data; 
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & data;
    }
};

static inline std::string generate_value() {
    static auto rand_char = boost::bind(boost::uniform_int<unsigned char>(0,255), boost::mt19937{});

    std::string s;
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(s), rand_char(), rand_char);
    return s;
}

using Map = std::map<unsigned int,myParam>;

Map generate_data(unsigned n) {
    Map map;

    for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
        map.emplace(i, myParam { generate_value() });

    return map;
}

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("/tmp/all_params", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);

        auto data = generate_data(10ul<<19);
        oa << data;
        std::cout << "Serialized " << data.size() << " entries\n";
    }
}
```

The file was 698miB on my system. The memory footprint looks like this (takes a while:)

```
==27420== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27420== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27420== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27420== Command: ./test
==27420== 
Serialized 5242880 entries
==27420== 
==27420== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27420==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27420==   total heap usage: 47,021,247 allocs, 47,021,247 frees, 3,069,877,283 bytes allocated
==27420== 
==27420== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27420==
```

The peak usage snapshot was at 1.2 GiB:

[image]

Of course you can optimize the memory layout, e.g. by using [Boost Flat Map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html) (with the `ordered_unique_range_t` insertion overloads!) and a custom allocator for e.g. the strings there. This will reduce/eliminate the overhead:

[image]

The tweaked code:

```
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/collections_load_imp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/collections_save_imp.hpp>
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <cassert>

namespace string_pool {
    static auto pool = []{
        std::vector<char> init;
        init.reserve(700ul<<20); // 700MiB
        return init;
    }();

    using entry = boost::string_ref;

    entry add(std::string const& s) {
        assert((pool.capacity() >= (pool.size() + s.size())));

        auto it = pool.end();
        pool.insert(it, s.begin(), s.end());
        return { &*it, s.size() };
    }

    static inline entry generate_random() {
        static auto rand_char = boost::bind(boost::uniform_int<unsigned char>(0,255), boost::mt19937{});

        static std::string s; // non-reentrant, but for lazy demo
        s.resize(rand_char());
        std::generate_n(s.begin(), s.size(), rand_char);
        return add(s);
    }
}

struct myParam { 
    string_pool::entry data;

    template <typename Ar> void save(Ar& ar, unsigned) const {
        std::string s = data.to_string();
        ar & s;
    }
    template <typename Ar> void load(Ar& ar, unsigned) {
        std::string s;
        ar & s;
        data = string_pool::add(s);
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};

// flat map serialization
namespace boost { 
namespace serialization {

    template<class Archive, typename...TArgs>
    inline void save(
        Archive & ar,
        const boost::container::flat_map<TArgs...> &t,
        const unsigned int /* file_version */
    ){
        boost::serialization::stl::save_collection<
            Archive, 
            boost::container::flat_map<TArgs...> 
        >(ar, t);
    }

    template<class Archive, typename...TArgs>
    inline void load(Archive & ar, boost::container::flat_map<TArgs...> &t, const unsigned int /* file_version */) {
        boost::serialization::stl::load_collection<Archive, boost::container::flat_map<TArgs...>,
            boost::serialization::stl::archive_input_map<Archive, boost::container::flat_map<TArgs...> >, 
            boost::serialization::stl::reserve_imp   <boost::container::flat_map<TArgs...> >
        >(ar, t);
    }

    // split non-intrusive serialization function member into separate
    // non intrusive save/load member functions
    template<class Archive, typename...TArgs>
    inline void serialize(Archive & ar, boost::container::flat_map<TArgs...> &t, const unsigned int file_version) {
        boost::serialization::split_free(ar, t, file_version);
    }
}
}

using Map = boost::container::flat_map<unsigned int,myParam>;

Map generate_data(unsigned n) {
    Map map;
    map.reserve(n);
    std::cout << "Capacity: " << map.capacity() << "\n";

    for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)
        map.emplace(i, myParam { string_pool::generate_random() });

    std::cout << "Capacity: " << map.capacity() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Total length: " << std::accumulate(
            map.begin(), map.end(), 0ul, [](size_t acc, Map::value_type const& v) {
                return acc + v.second.data.size();
            }) << "\n";
    return map;
}

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("/tmp/all_params", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);

        auto data = generate_data(10ul<<19);
        oa << data;
        std::cout << "Serialized " << data.size() << " entries\n";
    }
}
```

The md5sum of the generated `/tmp/all_params` file matched that of the first version: `ac75521dc0dc65585368677c834613cb`, proving that the data serialized is actually the same.

Comment: Provided a tweaked version using `boost::string_ref` and `boost::container::flat_map` that shows **a 32% reduced memory footprint** when properly reserved up-front. You'd want a smarter string pool in reality, but this should be a good demo to answer your question.